# Two different monitors with same resolution: text is a lot smaller on one of them

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have two 1920 x 1080 monitors (a Samsung & a BenQ), text size is set to 100% (Windows 10 settings) on both monitors.

Yet on the BenQ the text is significantly smaller (like, *too* small). But I can't fix that by setting text to 125% in Windows because in that case Chrome's viewport width changes which is unacceptable for my web dev work.

Why is the text size not identical on both monitors since they have the exact same resolution, and can I make it identical without using windows text zoom functionality?

Models are:

- [Samsung Syncmaster F2380](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-F2380-Inch-Widescreen-Monitor/dp/B002AGZU34)
- [BenQ GW2270H](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0157V5VJG/ref=oh_aui_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: What are the model numbers?

Comment: I just added them by editing my question.

Comment: The monitors have the same resolution, but is it _set_ to the same resolution?  Right click desktop -> screen resolution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two monitors have different screen sizes. 23 vs 21.5 inches. Naturally 1920 pixels will take up less space on the smaller monitor vs the larger. If you want your two monitors to look the same they need to have exactly the same screen sizes as well as pixel counts.